# Time series forecasting using SARIMAX (error in setting the correct start and end parameters)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, seaborn

I'm new in the time series tasks, and currently try to train and test a time series model using `SARIMAX` `(Seasonal Auto-Regressive Integrated Moving Average with eXogenous factors)`

My dataframe has 90 instances and it looks like this:

[image]

The range or the time series of this dataset is very short, it is just from 20-07-2020 to 18-10-2020.

The first thing I did is that I fit a `SARIMAX` model and make predictions on the testing set and plotting them. I specified the testing set to start from 1-10-2020 by specifying the `start` and `end` parameters `(start=70,end=89)`:

```
model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df['CH4'],order=(1, 1, 1),seasonal_order=(1,1,1,12))
results=model.fit()
df['forecast']=results.predict(start=70,end=89,dynamic=True)
df[['CH4','forecast']].plot(figsize=(12,8))
```

It gave me something like this (which is good):

[image]

Now, the codes worked well with me.

But I want to do one final thing, which is to make predictions on future values (after 18-10-2020) (not included in the dataset).  For example, I need to make predictions for the next two months (from 20-10-2020 to 20-12-2020) and plotting them.

This is the code:

```
future_dates=[df.index[-1]+ DateOffset(months=x)for x in range(0,24)]
future_datest_df=pd.DataFrame(index=future_dates[1:],columns=df.columns)

future_datest_df.tail()

future_df=pd.concat([df,future_datest_df])

future_df['forecast'] = results.predict(start = 90, end = 120, dynamic= True)
future_df[['CH4', 'forecast']].plot(figsize=(12, 8))
```

[image]

As we can see from the plot, there is something wrong. I think the problem is in using the `start` and `end`.

The plot should be continue from the last period of the testing set.

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be with the new data's index. After concatenating, does the index start again in the section of data that is from the future dataset?

if so, a simple solution would be:

```
future_df=pd.concat([df,future_datest_df]).reset_index(drop=True)
```